# COUNTIF in R with multiple restrictions

Tags: r, function, vector, subset, countif

I have event file data from retrosheet.org. This is data on baseball games formatted such that each observation is the description of each play in each game of a baseball season (complete with reference variables for game, player, and play).

```
> str(e.2015.1990)
'data.frame':   4813807 obs. of  42 variables:
 $ GAME.ID                              : Factor w/ 60464 levels "ANA201504100",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ INNING                               : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ BATTING.TEAM                         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ OUTS                                 : int  0 1 2 2 2 2 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ BATTER                               : Factor w/ 5107 levels "abrej003","ackld001",..: 73 167 33 120 163 100 34 256 200 209 ...
 $ BATTER.HAND                          : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ RES.BATTER                           : Factor w/ 5107 levels "abrej003","ackld001",..: 73 167 33 120 163 100 34 256 200 209 ...
 $ RES.BATTER.HAND                      : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ PITCHER                              : Factor w/ 3481 levels "abadf001","albem001",..: 187 187 187 187 187 187 204 204 204 187 ...
 $ PITCHER.HAND                         : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RES.PITCHER                          : Factor w/ 3481 levels "abadf001","albem001",..: 187 187 187 187 187 187 204 204 204 187 ...
 $ RES.PITCHER.HAND                     : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FIRST.RUNNER                         : Factor w/ 4369 levels "","abrej003",..: 1 1 1 1 104 140 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SECOND.RUNNER                        : Factor w/ 4048 levels "","abrej003",..: 1 1 1 26 1 90 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ THIRD.RUNNER                         : Factor w/ 3729 levels "","ackld001",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EVENT.TEXT                           : chr  "63/G" "6/P" "D8/L+" "S9/G.2-H" ...
 $ EVENT.TYPE                           : Factor w/ 21 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 1 1 19 18 18 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ AB.FLAG                              : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ HIT.VALUE                            : int  1 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SH.FLAG                              : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ SF.FLAG                              : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ DOUBLE.PLAY.FLAG                     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ TRIPLE.PLAY.FLAG                     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ RBI.ON.PLAY                          : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BATTED.BALL.TYPE                     : Factor w/ 5 levels "","F","G","L",..: 3 5 4 3 4 5 3 3 5 4 ...
 $ BATTER.DEST                          : int  0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RUNNER.ON.1ST.DEST                   : int  0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RUNNER.ON.2ND.DEST                   : int  0 0 0 4 0 2 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RUNNER.ON.3RD.DEST                   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SB.FOR.RUNNER.ON.1ST.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ SB.FOR.RUNNER.ON.2ND.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ SB.FOR.RUNNER.ON.3RD.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ CS.FOR.RUNNER.ON.1ST.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ CS.FOR.RUNNER.ON.2ND.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ CS.FOR.RUNNER.ON.3RD.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ PO.FOR.RUNNER.ON.1ST.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ PO.FOR.RUNNER.ON.2ND.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ PO.FOR.RUNNER.ON.3RD.FLAG            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ RESPONSIBLE.PITCHER.FOR.RUNNER.ON.1ST: Factor w/ 3433 levels "","albua001",..: 1 1 1 1 161 161 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RESPONSIBLE.PITCHER.FOR.RUNNER.ON.2ND: Factor w/ 3408 levels "","abadf001",..: 1 1 1 133 1 133 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RESPONSIBLE.PITCHER.FOR.RUNNER.ON.3RD: Factor w/ 3337 levels "","abadf001",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EVENT.NUM                            : Factor w/ 177 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 90 101 112 123 134 145 156 167 2 ...
```

From this, I would like to calculate game totals for each player for each game. I would like to format a data frame such that each observations is a description of one player's performance in one game of the season, and each PLAYER in each game composes the entirety of the observations.

I created a new database with two columns, GAME.ID and PLAYER.ID, such that each STARTER in each game composes the entirety of the observations.

```
> str(k.2015.1990)
'data.frame':   1146866 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ GAME.ID  : Factor w/ 60464 levels "ANA201504100",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ PLAYER.ID: Factor w/ 4699 levels "altuj001","bettm001",..: 11 11 11 12 14 12 12 24 24 24 ...
```

What I think I need to do next is create additional vectors (for each stat I want to calculate) such that each observation of said vector creates a unique subset of my event data, defined by:

```
e.2015.1990$GAME.ID = k.2015.1990$GAME.ID
e.2015.1990$PLAYER.ID = k.2015.1990$PLAYER.ID
```

and then calculates that stat from that subset. I know how to create vectors and subsets in R, but not vectors that create unique subsets for each observation. I think I need to use

```
function(x)
```

to do this; but, I am new to R and have no experience with this function.

I'm going to attempt to make a reproducible example for convenience's sake. In this example the goal is to calculate a hit total for each player in the first two games of the Angel's 2015 regular season.

I made a subset of the event file data consisting of the 156 observations that correspond to these two games. For simplicity's sake, I've included only the variables GAME.ID, BATTER, and HIT.VALUE.

```
         GAME.ID   BATTER HIT.VALUE
1   ANA201504100 escoa003         1
2   ANA201504100 mousm001         1
3   ANA201504100 cainl001         3
4   ANA201504100 hosme001         2
5   ANA201504100 morak001         2
6   ANA201504100 gorda001         1
7   ANA201504100 calhk001         1
8   ANA201504100 troum001         1
9   ANA201504100 pujoa001         1
10  ANA201504100 riosa002         1
11  ANA201504100 peres002         1
12  ANA201504100 infao001         1
13  ANA201504100 freed001         1
14  ANA201504100 cronc002         1
15  ANA201504100 aybae001         1
16  ANA201504100 escoa003         1
17  ANA201504100 mousm001         1
18  ANA201504100 cainl001         1
19  ANA201504100 hosme001         1
20  ANA201504100 morak001         1
21  ANA201504100 iannc001         1
22  ANA201504100 cowgc001         2
23  ANA201504100 giavj001         1
24  ANA201504100 calhk001         3
25  ANA201504100 troum001         1
26  ANA201504100 pujoa001         1
27  ANA201504100 gorda001         1
28  ANA201504100 riosa002         1
29  ANA201504100 peres002         1
30  ANA201504100 freed001         2
31  ANA201504100 cronc002         1
32  ANA201504100 aybae001         1
33  ANA201504100 iannc001         1
34  ANA201504100 infao001         1
35  ANA201504100 escoa003         2
36  ANA201504100 mousm001         1
37  ANA201504100 cainl001         2
38  ANA201504100 hosme001         1
39  ANA201504100 cowgc001         1
40  ANA201504100 giavj001         1
41  ANA201504100 calhk001         1
42  ANA201504100 morak001         5
43  ANA201504100 gorda001         1
44  ANA201504100 riosa002         1
45  ANA201504100 peres002         1
46  ANA201504100 troum001         2
47  ANA201504100 pujoa001         1
48  ANA201504100 freed001         5
49  ANA201504100 cronc002         1
50  ANA201504100 infao001         1
51  ANA201504100 escoa003         1
52  ANA201504100 mousm001         2
53  ANA201504100 cainl001         1
54  ANA201504100 cainl001         1
55  ANA201504100 aybae001         1
56  ANA201504100 iannc001         1
57  ANA201504100 joycm001         3
58  ANA201504100 giavj001         1
59  ANA201504100 hosme001         1
60  ANA201504100 morak001         1
61  ANA201504100 gorda001         1
62  ANA201504100 riosa002         1
63  ANA201504100 riosa002         1
64  ANA201504100 calhk001         1
65  ANA201504100 troum001         2
66  ANA201504100 pujoa001         1
67  ANA201504100 freed001         1
68  ANA201504100 peres002         2
69  ANA201504100 infao001         2
70  ANA201504100 escoa003         1
71  ANA201504100 mousm001         1
72  ANA201504100 cainl001         1
73  ANA201504100 hosme001         1
74  ANA201504100 morak001         1
75  ANA201504100 cronc002         1
76  ANA201504100 aybae001         1
77  ANA201504100 iannc001         1
78  ANA201504100 joycm001         1
79  ANA201504110 escoa003         1
80  ANA201504110 mousm001         1
81  ANA201504110 cainl001         1
82  ANA201504110 hosme001         1
83  ANA201504110 calhk001         5
84  ANA201504110 troum001         2
85  ANA201504110 pujoa001         1
86  ANA201504110 joycm001         1
87  ANA201504110 freed001         1
88  ANA201504110 morak001         1
89  ANA201504110 gorda001         1
90  ANA201504110 riosa002         1
91  ANA201504110 aybae001         2
92  ANA201504110 navae001         1
93  ANA201504110 buted001         1
94  ANA201504110 giavj001         1
95  ANA201504110 peres002         1
96  ANA201504110 infao001         1
97  ANA201504110 escoa003         1
98  ANA201504110 giavj001         1
99  ANA201504110 calhk001         1
100 ANA201504110 troum001         1
101 ANA201504110 mousm001         5
102 ANA201504110 cainl001         2
103 ANA201504110 hosme001         1
104 ANA201504110 hosme001         1
105 ANA201504110 morak001         3
106 ANA201504110 gorda001         1
107 ANA201504110 riosa002         2
108 ANA201504110 peres002         5
109 ANA201504110 infao001         2
110 ANA201504110 escoa003         1
111 ANA201504110 pujoa001         1
112 ANA201504110 joycm001         1
113 ANA201504110 freed001         1
114 ANA201504110 mousm001         1
115 ANA201504110 cainl001         1
116 ANA201504110 hosme001         2
117 ANA201504110 morak001         2
118 ANA201504110 gorda001         1
119 ANA201504110 riosa002         1
120 ANA201504110 aybae001         1
121 ANA201504110 navae001         1
122 ANA201504110 buted001         2
123 ANA201504110 giavj001         1
124 ANA201504110 calhk001         3
125 ANA201504110 troum001         2
126 ANA201504110 pujoa001         1
127 ANA201504110 riosa002         1
128 ANA201504110 peres002         2
129 ANA201504110 infao001         1
130 ANA201504110 escoa003         2
131 ANA201504110 mousm001         1
132 ANA201504110 joycm001         1
133 ANA201504110 freed001         1
134 ANA201504110 aybae001         1
135 ANA201504110 cainl001         1
136 ANA201504110 hosme001         1
137 ANA201504110 morak001         2
138 ANA201504110 gorda001         1
139 ANA201504110 riosa002         1
140 ANA201504110 navae001         1
141 ANA201504110 iannc001         1
142 ANA201504110 giavj001         1
143 ANA201504110 peres002         1
144 ANA201504110 infao001         1
145 ANA201504110 escoa003         1
146 ANA201504110 calhk001         1
147 ANA201504110 troum001         1
148 ANA201504110 pujoa001         1
149 ANA201504110 mousm001         2
150 ANA201504110 cainl001         1
151 ANA201504110 hosme001         1
152 ANA201504110 morak001         1
153 ANA201504110 gorda001         1
154 ANA201504110 joycm001         1
155 ANA201504110 freed001         1
156 ANA201504110 aybae001         1
```

I've also made a subset of the new database that corresponds to the 40 starters in these two games.

```
             GAME.ID PLAYER.ID
1       ANA201504100  escoa003
60465   ANA201504100  mousm001
120929  ANA201504100  cainl001
181393  ANA201504100  hosme001
241857  ANA201504100  morak001
302321  ANA201504100  gorda001
362785  ANA201504100  riosa002
423249  ANA201504100  peres002
483713  ANA201504100  infao001
1117610 ANA201504100  vargj001
573434  ANA201504100  calhk001
633898  ANA201504100  troum001
694362  ANA201504100  pujoa001
754826  ANA201504100  freed001
815290  ANA201504100  cronc002
875754  ANA201504100  aybae001
936218  ANA201504100  iannc001
996682  ANA201504100  cowgc001
1057146 ANA201504100  giavj001
1117613 ANA201504100  santh001
2       ANA201504110  escoa003
60466   ANA201504110  mousm001
120930  ANA201504110  cainl001
181394  ANA201504110  hosme001
241858  ANA201504110  morak001
302322  ANA201504110  gorda001
362786  ANA201504110  riosa002
423250  ANA201504110  peres002
483714  ANA201504110  infao001
2100000 ANA201504110  guthj001
573435  ANA201504110  calhk001
633899  ANA201504110  troum001
694363  ANA201504110  pujoa001
754827  ANA201504110  joycm001
815291  ANA201504110  freed001
875755  ANA201504110  aybae001
936219  ANA201504110  navae001
996683  ANA201504110  buted001
1057147 ANA201504110  giavj001
2100001 ANA201504110  weavj003
```

I would think there should be a way to add a column to this latter database such that each observation references the GAME.ID and PLAYER.ID entry on its row, searches the former database to isolate those observations where GAME.ID = GAME.ID and PLAYER.ID = BATTER, counts the number of observations in that subset where HIT.VALUE > 1 (1 = default, 2 = single, 3 = double, 4 = triple, and 5 = homerun), and then returns that count to the observation. In excel, this might be done with a CountIf() function that I could easily copy the length of the vector. I don't know how to do it in R, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for. It groups the 2nd to last dataset by `GAME.ID` and `BATTER` and then counts the number of hits per group that are >1.

```
library(data.table)
dt<-setDT(df)[, list(count_hits = sum(HIT.VALUE>1)),by=c("GAME.ID","BATTER")]

head(dt)
        GAME.ID   BATTER count_hits
1: ANA201504100 escoa003          1
2: ANA201504100 mousm001          1
3: ANA201504100 cainl001          2
4: ANA201504100 hosme001          1
5: ANA201504100 morak001          2
6: ANA201504100 gorda001          0
```

Another option in base R is:

```
res<-aggregate(x=list(count_hits=df$HIT.VALUE), by=list(GAME.ID=df$GAME.ID,BATTER=df$BATTER), FUN = function(x) sum(x>1) )

head(res)
       GAME.ID   BATTER count_hits
1 ANA201504100 aybae001          0
2 ANA201504110 aybae001          1
3 ANA201504110 buted001          1
4 ANA201504100 cainl001          2
5 ANA201504110 cainl001          1
6 ANA201504100 calhk001          1
```